# SVG as a div background

Tags: html, css, svg

What I am trying to do is have an animated SVG background similar to what is achieved here, for learning: https://conference.laravel.com/

It seems I can't do with this a css svg background so I need to create the elements inline with the html. This is how far I got:

**Full code**

http://jsfiddle.net/C8d34/13/

I want the svg stage to take up the full blue area so I can put svg elements inside and apply animations like in the first link. However, my header menu content forces the svg outside of the blue area.

How can I make it sit behind the content and not be pushed down by it? Is creating another div the only way?

**My SVG code**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"> /* this here */
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

However because there is other content in the box, and I want my svg to take up 100% of the blue area, it forces the SVG down.

**Question**

I want to have an animated svg background in the blue area with multiple animated elements. However, the header is pushing the whole svg area downwards off the blue area. How do I make it appear like a background and have my content on top?

Comment: Please strip out all the HTML & CSS that is NOT required to show the primary issue from your JSfiddle. It's incredibly hard to deal with a load of code that isn't required.

Comment: this is what you are looking? http://jsfiddle.net/C8d34/14/

Comment: @KheemaPandey Yes I think it is, can you tell me how you did it please?

Comment: @KheemaPandey I can't click the links this way though at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave the `z-index` property to `nav` element so the link could be click-able. and use `position:absolute` for SVG element. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C8d34/17/)**.

```
svg {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
div.buttons{position:absolute; bottom:0;} /*div contains the buttons like Free Trial*/
nav{position:relative;z-index:1;}
```

Comment: In TailwindCss: className="absolute bottom-0 top-0 left-0 z-0"

Answer (score 0):

## [SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/noved/1/edit)

This is the CSS rule that's is causing the problem:

```
.full_height { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the 100%